# Creating a very simple game in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a game in JS, and I faced a problem.

I got an 2D array that stores an image, now I want some random pic to be changed every 1 second, everything is working but, I don't know how I can change the picture.

Do I have to print all the other images if I want to change the random cell in the array?

I'm almost sure that there's another way to change it without doing it.

I'll be glad for help, if anyone needs other explanation I'll be glad to.

Comment: Show us what code you have so far.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y9PqsLZK @Treebranch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using something like this in your header. It should call `changePic()` every second, incrementing through your picture array, and setting the new picture on an image element.

```
//know your array sizes
var max_x = picArr.length;
var max_y = picArr[0].length;
var current_x = 0;
var current_y = 0;

function changePic()
{
  if(current_y == max_y-1)
  {
    if(current_x == max_x-1)
    {
      current_x = 0;
      current_y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      current_x++;
      current_y = 0;
    }
  }
  else
    current_y++;

  var pic = picArr[current_x][current_y];
  getElementById('randomImage').setAttribute('src', pic);

  window.setTimeout(changePic, 1000);
}

setTimeout(changePic, 1000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

I would start out with something like

```
var ImageOne = new Image();
ImageOne.src = "UrlToImage";
```

And so on just to make sure all the images are loaded when the game starts

Thereafter I would be using jQuery:

```
$("#IdOfImg").attr("src", ImageOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a css class for the  elements with a background image rather dan adding images to the DOM. I think a css class for back.png and one for the 1.png should do the trick.

Toggle the classes on the td elements every second.

Hope this helps.